# Dynamically transform html to component in angular4/angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I've got an external module which takes an html string, converts it to html and adds it to the dom. This looks like this:

```
dialogDefinition.addContents({
    title: 'Upload',
    id: 'upload',
    label: 'Upload',
    elements: [{
        type: 'html',
        html: '<media-upload></media-upload>'
    }]
});
```

What I want is that the `media-upload`-Component gets rendered by angular so that I can reuse my existing component logic.

How can I get angular to initialize the dynamically added components, when the html content doesn't come from a template?

In angular1 there is the $compile-function for such situations, but I don't find the equivalent or an other working solution for angular4/angular2.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Angular.io has a really good doc on how to load components dynamically:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've seen that before. But it only describes the case where you've got the template under your control - I don't have control over the dom-creation and that's the main problem where I got stuck.